# C++ Bubble Sort with offset?

Tags: c++

First of all, this is a homework assignment. I'm trying to make some bubbleSort function in C++ with an offset. The function must take an array input with an offset with count elements.

For example: `a[5] = {90, 9, 2, 10, 5}` -> `bubbleSort(a, 1, 4)` -> `{90, 2, 5, 9, 10}`

Currently here is what my code looks like :

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int offset, int count) {
    bool swapped = true;
    int pivot = offset;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        pivot++;
            for (offset ; offset < count - pivot; offset ++) {
                if (arr[offset] > arr[offset+1]) {
                    arr[offset] ^= arr[offset+1];
                    arr[offset+1] ^= arr[offset];
                    arr[offset] ^= arr[offset+1];
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I think my offset checking is off the index, could you please tell me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than getting all tangled up with the offset, think of the problem like this:

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int offset, int count)
{
   StandardBubbleSort(&arr[offset], count);
}

void StandardBubbleSort(int arr[], int count)
{
// the standard algorithm from your text book
}
```

Comment: Thanks, try implementing it now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if it works for you.

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int offset, int count) {  
    offset--;

    for (; offset < count; offset ++) 
        for(int j=0;j<count-1;j++)
        {
            if (arr[offset] > arr[offset+1]) {
                int temp=arr[offset];
                arr[offset]=arr[offset+1];
                arr[offset+1]=temp;
            }
        }
}
```